# Event Click Mouse Button to 3D TextMeshPro

Tags: unity, c#, scripting, text-mesh-pro

Im create TextMeshPro from "Create -> 3D Object ->Text - TextMeshPro"
How to receive mouse button click event for TextMeshPro?
I tried via Physics.Raycast/Collider but it doesn't work. It's not "Create -> UI ->Text - TextMeshPro" though.
I also tried to add GraphicRaycaster component to TextMeshPro as for UI element, but it doesn't work.I did not understand where to create EventSystem. I just added it as a component to TextMeshPro.
Also tried to add Button Component to TextMeshPro.

```csharp
public class Math : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    GraphicRaycaster m_Raycaster;
    PointerEventData m_PointerEventData;
    void Start()
    {
        m_Raycaster = GameObject.Find("Solution").GetComponent<TextMeshPro>().GetComponent<GraphicRaycaster>();
        m_EventSystem = GameObject.Find("Solution").GetComponent<TextMeshPro>().GetComponent<EventSystem>();
        Solution = GameObject.Find("Solution").GetComponent<TextMeshPro>();
    }
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            m_PointerEventData = new PointerEventData(null);
            m_PointerEventData.position = Input.mousePosition;
            List<RaycastResult> results = new List<RaycastResult>();
            m_Raycaster.Raycast(m_PointerEventData, results);
            foreach (RaycastResult result in results) //Results - null
            {
                Debug.Log("Hit " + result.gameObject.name); //not enter
            }
            Ray ray = GetComponent<Camera>().ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
            RaycastHit hit;
            if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit))
            {
                if (hit.collider.gameObject.name == "Solution")
                {
                    Debug.Log("Hit " + hit.collider.gameObject.name); //not enter
                }
            }
        }
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what I changed. It seems that nothing has changed. But the BoxCollider method just started working. Thanks to all who responded.